# Dart 3.3: Why extension types not working?

Tags: flutter, dart

I am trying to use new feature in Dart 3.3 - Extension types. Simple example from [doc](https://dart.dev/language/extension-types):

```
extension type IdNumber(int id) {
  // Wraps the 'int' type's '<' operator:
  operator <(IdNumber other) => id < other.id;
  // Doesn't declare the '+' operator, for example,
  // because addition does not make sense for ID numbers.
}
```

but in the word `type` there is an error:

`This requires the 'inline-class' language feature to be enabled.`

My Flutter version:

```
Flutter 3.19.0 • channel stable • https://github.com/flutter/flutter.git
Framework • revision bae5e49bc2 (6 days ago) • 2024-02-13 17:46:18 -0800
Engine • revision 04817c99c9
Tools • Dart 3.3.0 • DevTools 2.31.1
```

I was trying to add this in pubspec.yaml but it's not working:

```yaml
analyzer:
  enable-experiment:
    - inline-class
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The full error message actually tells you what to do

[image]

> This requires the 'inline-class' language feature to be enabled.
> Try updating your pubspec.yaml to set the minimum SDK constraint to 3.3.0 or higher, and running 'pub get'.

So, if you maybe have this in your `pubspec.yaml`

```
sdk: ">=3.0.0 <4.0.0"
```

change it to

```
sdk: ">=3.3.0 <4.0.0"
```

Comment: for some reason I don't have this full description. that's works. thank you.

Comment: @VladyslavUlianytskyi Ah okay. I'm using Android Studio. Maybe you are using a different IDE that doesn't show it.